# Google Apps Script Custom Function (permission issues Google Sheet to Calendar)

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script that updates entries on a Google Calendar based on a list of dates on Google Sheets.

The script runs well if I run it from the editor or if I trigger the function via a Menu entry.

When I try to trigger it via custom function in sheets, it's returning an error: "You do not have permission to call getCalendarById "

Both the sheet and the calendar are under the same Google Account.

Is there a limitation with regards to triggering calendar calls from inside google sheets?

Answer (score 1):

> There are restriction for custom functions that you can put into spreadsheet cell.  You should check [the documention](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) to be sure that you comply with all of the requirements.

Comment: Looks like anything that requires authorization can't be used as a custom function. Thanks. Just got started with apps script from javascript. I should start reading the docs before starting on a new method/class. But I sometimes forget it when I pursue a train of thought. :D